# how to consider 2 row as column names for importing excels to sql server using SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, excel-2007, bids

I am importing Excel data to DB using **SSIS** package.

The problem is i want to consider **second Row i.e A2:Z2 as column name.**

I **don't** want to take **A1:Z1** into consideration.

How can i achieve it.

**My researched [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415838/ssis-excel-to-sql-import-first-6-rows-of-the-file-contains-header-related-inf) [Link 2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/66379b0e-4cab-476e-bbb8-c8640c8c0c03/)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a sample excel file with the data like

[image]

In excel source use `SQL Command` for `Data access mode` and write the query to skip the initial row

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A2:B]
--In your case it will be [Sheet1$A2:Z]
```

and in the excel connection manager select the option `First Rows as Column name`

[image]

When i try to preview it ,i get the data from the 2nd row onwards

[image]

Comment: I ain't getting option like **Data access mode**. I am getting **4** options i.e **Properties->Access Mode** `1.OpenRowSet 2.OpenRowSet From Variable 3.SQL command 4.SQL command From Variable`. I Used SQL Command but that didn't help.

Comment: My apologies .i actually meant `SQL Command` in `Data access mode`.BTW r u getting any error ? can u post some sample data and don't forget to mark the `checkbox` to select `First Row as Column names`

Comment: I don't know I tried the same **First Time**, I got an **error** but now it's working Fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have to say WHERE ID IS NOT NULL? Or is this automatically handled? I am trying to understand how does ssis known which row to stop at?