# Extract data from a specific cell with SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Say I have an Excel table with headers in the third row.

```
|Table title
|Entry Date: September 15, 2015
|    ColumnA    |    ColumnB    |    (etc.)    |
```

With SSIS, I would like to import everything below the headers and append it to an existing SQL table with columns

```
EntryDate    ColumnA     ColumnB    (...)
```

The steps would be

1. Import the data below the headers
2. Select the cell that contains the date
3. Extract the date from its string
4. Fill the EntryDate column in the SQL table

I found [a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12416379/4897271) to define a row from which to import, but SSIS did not accept the formatting and reverted to the table name. I haven't found a solution to importing the dates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make the OPENROWSET work. I would do it in a Script Task with VB myself.

For your date, I would use

```
DateValue = Replace(Workbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, 1), "Entry Date: ", "")
```

The I would start on row 3 and get the headers (if needed) and then import the data line by line by.

I don't have everything you need but here's something to check out to get you started. You do need some VB knowledge to put all the pieces together.

```
    'Declare variables
    Dim objConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim objCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim objRS As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Excel1 As New Excel.Application
    Dim Workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim Worksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim Query As String

    Dim CellValue As String
    Dim Row As Integer

    Public Sub Main()

        objConn = New ADODB.Connection
        objCmd = New ADODB.Command
        objRS = New ADODB.Recordset

        'Open Connection
        objConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1; Data Source=KPRD; Initial Catalog = REPORTING; User ID=user; PWD=Password1; Persist Security Info=True; Auto Translate=False; Connection Timeout=300;"
        objConn.Open()

        'Set and Excecute SQL Command
        Query = Dts.Variables("SQLData").Value.ToString

        objCmd.ActiveConnection = objConn
        objCmd.CommandText = Query
        objCmd.CommandTimeout = 120

        'Open Recordset
        objRS.Source = objCmd
        objRS.Open() 

        Excel1.Visible = False
        Excel1.DisplayAlerts = False

        ReportName = "\\ServerName\folder\Report.xlxs"      

        Row = 2

        DateValue = Replace(Workbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, 1), "Entry Date: ", "")

        Workbook = Excel1.Workbooks.Open(ReportName, , False) 'False = read-write.

        Do Until Workbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(Row, 1) = ""

        'Get data from a row

        'Write SQL to insert data into your db

GetNextRow:
        Row = Row + 1
        Loop

Done:
        Excel1.Quit()
        Excel1 = Nothing
        ReportName = Nothing
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

ExitSub:
        Exit Sub
```